# Can I see a Facebook post's reach from my app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm very new to the Facebook API, and I was wondering if I can see a user's Facebook post's reach. For example, my iOS app contains a photo, that photo is shared to Facebook. Can I (the developer) see how many likes and shares (ie. reach) that photo has? Does this work with links? Is this possible if the user shares from a web app? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: No, you can´t.

You can only get the likes and shares if you authorize that user with the `user_posts` permission. After that, you can read his posts with his User Token.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. You're saying I can't see the reach on the post, but can't I (with the user's and Facebook's permission) check which posts are from my app and see their reach?

Comment: you would need an extra permission, and you will most likely not get it approved in the review process just for getting the reach of a post.

Comment: so basically you can´t, that´s the simple answer ;)

Comment: btw, i dont think you can check if a post came from your app, but storing post ids after posting would be no big deal. you would need to post with publish_actions though, and not just with a share dialog. a lot of things to consider, and the review process is where it will most likely stop you (because the user does not benefit in any way from the information).

Comment: Ohh ok. Thank you for clearing that up and giving further explanation.